# How to handle password Strings in ADF Faces?

Tags: java, jsf, passwords, oracle-adf

Per company policy (and other recommendations), we should not use String class to handle passwords. Because this objects are immutable and may live until the GC deallocates it, so a "memory inspection" could show a not yet deallocated String containing the password. So the alternative is to use char[] instead and overwrite it contents once is no longer needed. However, when using an 
inputText component, the setter method must receive a String.

I have an inputText like:

```
<af:inputText value="{myBean.password}" secret="true"/>
```

And

```
public class MyBean {
...
   private transient char[] password;
...
   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password.toCharArray();
   }
...
   public void sumbit(ActionEvent e) {
     ...
     //Wipe password
     for(int i = 0 ; i < password.length ; i++) { password[i] = ' '; }
     password = null;
   }
}
```

As you can see, there is still a String object containing the password (the argument of the setter), and I don't know how to deal with that value. Is there any way to receive a char[] value? Does the cycle of ADF contemplates the fact that this is a password and should do something special?

This is a server and calling the CG is not a good idea.

Comment: can you use a converter for it? I mean javax.faces.convert.converter

Comment: oh nevermind... the converter will convert to a string...

Comment: why don't you use some virtual keyboard or something like this?

Comment: Implement your own password component :)

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think is passing the value of the password field from client to server in an encrypted format using JavaScript encryption libraries and decrypt it on the server. This way the receiving string will be in a non plain text format.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping the value of the component in the bean, keep a reference to the component itself:

```
<af:inputText bindings="{myBean.password}" secret="true"/>

......
private RichInputText password;
......
public void setPassword(RichInputText password) {
  this.password = password;
}

public RichInputText getPassword() {
  return password;
}
```

and in action listener get the value from the component:

```
public void sumbit(ActionEvent e) {
char[] pswd = password.getValue().toCharArray();
............
}
```

Hope this helps.